# javascript split an array of dates by date range

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have an array of consecutive dates for a whole year (`all`).

I also have an array with 2 date ranges (`datesArray`).

I'm looping through the first array and getting the index of the other array for that date which either returns an index or -1.

I then compare that index with the previous index to see if there is a match

If the -1 is found, I need to create an array and add the date. If the next date is also -1, I want to add to the newly created array, otherwise do nothing.

I should end up with 2 separate arrays, 1 for each date range

```
var prev = '';
var array = [];
var j = 0;

$.each(all, function(i,v) {
    var index = datesArray.map(Number).indexOf(+v);

    if(index === prev) {
        array[j].push(v);
    }
    else if(index === -1) {
        array[j] = v;

        j++;
    }

    prev = datesArray.map(Number).indexOf(+v);

});
```

How would i finish my code to create these 2 new arrays or even better slit the `datesArray` in 2 between the last date of the first range and the first date of the second?

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected results in order to create a [mcve]

Comment: Why `$.each` when the built-in *forEach* is available and doesn't require support from an external library? Why convert *datesArray* to an array of numbers on every iteration? What type are the values in the arrays, I guess Dates?

Comment: @RobG, yes they are all dates

Comment: Please see charlietfl's comment, a small sample data set is essential. Without more information, answers will just be guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself after searching on here

```
var ranges = function() {
    var today,
        oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
        prev = new Date(datesArray[0]),
        range = [];

    $.each(datesArray, function(i,v) {

        if(i === 0) {
            prev = datesArray[i];
        }
        else {
            prev = datesArray[i - 1];   
        }

        var d = new Date(prev); // today!
        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((v.getTime() - d.getTime()) / (oneDay)));

        if(diffDays > 1 || (datesArray.length - 1) === i) {
            range.push(i);
        }
    });

    return range;
};
```